# angular.js:13550 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-material

I have ben having a look at other queries with the same problem but not the same problem due to I'm not receiving/sending data at the moment the error arises.

The error arises just when I click on a button to show a modal dialog. Here is the code executed by the ng-click:

```
$scope.copyCollection = function(ev, name, cid) {
      angular.element(document).ready(function () {
          $mdDialog.show({
              controller: DialogController,
              templateUrl: 'templateCopyCollection.html',
              parent: angular.element(document.body),
              targetEvent: ev,
              clickOutsideToClose:true,
              locals: {
                  name: name,
                  id: cid
              }
          })
          .then(function(name_collection) {
              angular.element(document).ready(function () {
                  service.copy_collection(name_collection, cid).then( function (response) {
                      console.info('copied', response);
                  }, function () {
                      console.info('error', response);
                  });
              });
           });
       });
};
```

As you can see, the function shows the Dialog first and it's in such moment when the error come up.

I do not understand what's happening and the error in console do not show in what part of my code make it happen.

Any idea?

Comment: Why are you using `angular.element(document).ready` ?

Comment: @MartijnWelker Only for testing purposes. I can delete it.

Comment: could you open your network tab and check which requests fire when opening the modal ? on the the responses of that request should start with `<`, could you post that ?

Comment: If your app here making some request to server, probably server answered not with json like {'status':200} , but answered with html , like <!DOCTYPE html>...
<html> ERROR MESSAGE </html>, so some function trying to parse json response, but it is not json, and starting with "<" symbol ( <!DOCTY...>)

Comment: @DmitryYudin, As I mentioned, at the moment I open the Modal Dialog, there is not call to the server side. That's the strange situation.

Comment: @MartijnWelker  Thanks for your advice! There is an old function that make a call to the server. That's the problem. Thanks!!!!!